# html_entities in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities

Here i have a textbox in which user inputs html tags like `<h1>hello</h1>` then i append that text to a td with

```
 var text = $('textbox').val();
 $('table').append('<tr><td style="padding:0px 12px;color:black">'+(text)+'</td></tr>');
```

Now what i want is the text in the td should come text as entered `<h1>hello</h1>` and not hello with h1 tag

I tried escape and unscape but it didnt helped

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript/JQuery HTML Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used encode function from here [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

 var text = htmlEncode($('textbox').val());
 $('table').append('<tr><td style="padding:0px 12px;color:black">'+(text)+'</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a plain JavaScript function without the jQuery overkill:

```
function htmlEncode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[<>&"']/g, function($0) { return "&" + {"<":"lt",">":"gt","&":"amp",'"':"quot","'":"#39"}[$0] + ";"; });
}
```

This looks for any occurrence of `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, and `'`, calls the function that then looks up the matched character and returns the corresponding character reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the < by &lt; and > by &gt;

```
var text = $('textbox').val();
text = text.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
$('table').append('<tr><td style="padding:0px 12px;color:black">'+(text)+'</td></tr>');
```

You can test it yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/W7RWA/

Comment: Doing this kind of things with vanilla JavaScript kind of beats the purpose of using a framework.

Comment: This does not encode & as &amp; so the string "<&amp;>" will incorrectly encode to the HTML equivalent of the plain text string "<&>".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the node value with the [val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
// Untested
var text = $('textbox').val();
var tr = $('<tr><td style="padding:0px 12px;color:black"></td></tr>');
tr.find("td").val(text);
$('table').append(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want html_entities ....

try the phpjs project

https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/strings/htmlentities.js

.. it also requires this function though https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/strings/get_html_translation_table.js

Answer (score 0):

[PHPJS](http://www.phpjs.org) is an excellent resource for these sorts of "How can I use this PHP function in Javascript?" questions.

Javascript [htmlentities()](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425)

Comment: Wow, I came to the party late. Sorry!